# Multilevel models comparison and diagnostics in Stata

Tags: regression, stata, multilevel-analysis

I'm working with three level models in Stata using `mixed` [command](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/memixed.pdf). Taking reproducible example from the manual:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r14/productivity

mixed gsp || region: || state:
est store null

mixed gsp private emp hwy water other unemp || region: || state:
est store adjusted
```

Princeton's [website](http://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/Multilevel101.pdf) pointed me to first steps on how to compare models:

```
lrtest null adjusted
```

And assess normality of residuals

```
predict resid_std, rstandard
qnorm resid_std
```

I (think) I can also check the plot of residuals versus fitted values:

```
predict resid, res
predict fit, fit

graph twoway scatter (resid fit), yline(0)
```

And get AIC & BIC with:

```
estat ic
```

Are there any other tools that will help me compare models and assess their fit?